# Integral inequality - Proof techniques

Tags: inequality

I would like to prove that the function
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^a f(s) s \mathrm{d}s - \frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x f(s) s \mathrm{d}s $$  is non-positive for $x \in [0, a] $, given that the function $f$ is continuous, positive and non-increasing over the same interval.

I think I managed as I show afterwards: I still would like to see how it could be done more concisely/elegantly/effectively.

My first approach: firstly I compute the derivative of $F$, 
$$ F ^\prime (x) = \Big[- \frac{1}{x^2} f(x)  x + \frac{2}{x^3} \int_0^x f(s) s \mathrm{d}s \Big] $$

As $f(x)$ is non-increasing, the following inequality stands

$$  \frac{2}{x} \int_0^xf(s) s \mathrm{d}s \geq 2f(x) x$$
and then
$$ F ^\prime(x) = [- \frac{1}{x^2} f(x)  x + \frac{2}{x^3} \int_0^x f(s) s \mathrm{d}s ] \geq   \frac{1}{x^2} [-f(x)  x +2f(x) x]  = \frac{1}{x^2} f(x) > 0$$

I compute then $F(0)$.
As $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x f(s) s \mathrm{d}s = \frac{1}{2}f(0)$$ it follows that 
$$F(0) =  \frac{1}{a^2}\int_0^a f(s) s \mathrm{d}s - \frac{1}{2}f(0)$$ which is non-positive (it is actually nihil when $f$ is constant)
As $F(0)  \leq 0$, $F(a) = 0$ and $F$ is non-decreasing, I conclude it must be non-positive, a desired.

The second approach I thought about is consists in arguing that the expression
$$\frac{x^2} {a^2} \leq \frac { \int_0^x f(s) s \mathrm{d}s } {\int_0^a f(s) s \mathrm{d}s }$$
stands.
One notices that the equality stands if $f(x)$ is constant. As $f(x)$ is non increasing, the second term must be larger than in the case of costant $f(x)$, which proves the claim.

As said, I would like to know how the same claim can be proved in more efficient/elegant/coincise fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality is a direct result of [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem).

Note that $F(x) \leq 0$ can be equivalently written as 
$$\frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^x s\,ds} \geq \frac{\int_{0}^a f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^a s\,ds}. $$
From Cauchy's mean value theorem, we can show that $\exists \,\xi \in (0, x), \eta \in (x, a)$ such that
$$
 f(\xi) = \frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^x s\,ds}, \,f(\eta) = \frac{\int_{x}^a f(s)s \,ds}{\int_x^a s\,ds}.
$$
Since $f(x)$ is non-increasing, we have $f(\xi) \geq f(\eta)$, i.e., 
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^x s\,ds} \geq \frac{\int_{x}^a f(s)s \,ds}{\int_x^a s\,ds}.
$$
As a result,
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^x s\,ds} \geq \frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)s \,ds + \int_{x}^a f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^x s\,ds + \int_x^a s\,ds} = \frac{\int_{0}^a f(s)s \,ds}{\int_0^a s\,ds},
$$
where we haved use the following fact for ratios：

> Suppose $a, b, c, d > 0$, then
>   $$\frac{a}{b}  \geq \frac{c}{d}  \implies \frac{a}{b} \geq \frac{a + c}{b + d} .$$

---

In general, when $f(x), g(x)$ are positive and continuous, and $f(x)$ is non-increasing, we have
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^x f(s)g(s) \,ds}{\int_0^x g(s)\,ds} \geq \frac{\int_{0}^a f(s)g(s) \,ds}{\int_0^a g(s)\,ds}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought about your approach but then I have also to say, what I did is shorter. Thank you a lot anyhow, much appreciated

Comment: @Anaedonist Thanks. I have fixed some typos, and please see the latest version. IMHO, although this method seems wordy, it reveals some intrinsic properties of this problem, and can be generalized :)